# Make a stored procedure that sends an automated email using sql express

Tags: sql, vba, sql-server-express

I have created a stored procedure below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CustomerLimit
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT customername,creditlimit,outsanding FROM customer where creditlimit < outstanding
END
```

I am trying to have this information sent as an email whenever the conditions of the select script are true 
this is what I have created to be able to send the email to a specific user in the database but am unsuccessful since am using sql express

```
USE msdb;
GO

EXEC sp_send_dbmail
```

Comment: Instead of switching the database, just execute the stored procedure with fully qualified name (exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail). But it isn't clear what do you want to send in the message body? Did you manage to setup database mail successfully? Actually do you ask how to set it up or how to construct e-mails body from your query result?

Comment: I am using sql express is it possible to set up database email with sql sql express please share the procedure

Comment: Yes, it is possible to send e-mail with SQL Server Express. Here is how to set it up. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/